# Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Int’ in Haskell

Tags: haskell

`place n x` is meant to find the place of integer `n` in the list `x`, for example `place 2 [1,2,3]` will return `1`:

```
place :: Int -> [a] -> Int
place n x = length $ takeWhile (/=n) x
```

But it gets the error `Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Int’`

Why? `takeWhile` should return a list and its length is an integer, hence `place` should output an `Int` eventually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct type signature for `place` is:

```
place :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
```

When you use `[a]` in place of `[Int]` you are saying that `place` will work on a list of *any* type. For instance, I could call it like this:

```
place 3 [True, False, False, True]
```

or call it with a list of Char:

```
place 4 "this is a test"
```

But neither of these can work because `takeWhile` will compare each element of the list against the Int `n`. This forces the list to be a list of Ints.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `(/=) :: Eq ty => ty -> ty -> Bool` where that second `ty ~ Int` due to the type of `n`.  If `ty` is `Int` then the type of the other argument of `(/=)` (`x`) must be `Int` too.

Answer (score 2):

> find the place of integer `n` in the list `x`

ah, but there are no integers in the list at all. The type is `[a]`. Only if the type were `[Int]` would it be possible to find an `n` in it.

Now, you might say “`[Int]` is *a possible instantiation* of `[a]`, so it could still work in that case”. Well, it could – but *only* in that case, and therefore it would be stupid not to enforce `a ~ Int` in the type signature.

More reasonably, you might want to find *any type of number* which happens to be equal to the integer `n`. Well, you can do that:

```
place' :: (Num a, Eq a) => Int -> [a] -> Int
place' n = length . takeWhile (/= fromIntegral n)
```

Here, I first *convert* `n` to the type of number that's contained in the list, and then compare it with those numbers.

Comment: It's not that it would be *stupid*, it's that it's a mistake. Which is perfectly fine: everyone makes mistakes. That being said, why don't you go for the more general type  `Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int` for `place'`?

Comment: @gallais: that would indeed be a rather more useful type, but it's not strictly more general (e.g. can't look up an integer in a list of floats... which, of course, might not be a reasonable thing to do anyway).